# Why does my regexp not tell me if a string contains no numbers?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, numbers

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I check if a string doesn't contain any numbers?  I'm trying this

```
2.4.0 :002 > line = "abcdef"
 => "abcdef"

2.4.0 :007 > line =~ /^^[0-9]+$/
 => nil
```

I thought the "^" was the "not" character, but I'm not sure how it works because I know it is also the phrase starting character.  Anyway, help is appreciated, -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^` negates a set of characters when at the beginning of the square-bracketed list:

```
[^abc]  # not a, b, or c
```

so you just need to move it inside the brackets:

```
line =~ /^[^0-9]+$/
```

Note that you probably want `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$`, since they match the starts and ends of entire strings instead of lines, and that `\D` is short for `[^0-9]`.

```
line =~ /\A\D+\z/
```

You can also do a negative check for digits.

```
line !~ /\d/
```

Comment: Good, but imo mention of the negative lookahead weakens your answer.  I don't see why you need anchors or `+` in the negative test and consider using `\d` .

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Good point; I tried to expand a bit. The anchor is because `/^\d+$/` wouldn’t match `2blah`, so its negation should.

Comment: It's also a good habit to use `\A` in preference to `^` since it anchors to the beginning of the string, not the beginning of a line. The difference can be very, very important: `"foo\n123".match(/^\d+$/)` does match even you think it wouldn't.

Comment: Just saw that now. Would be nice to have a recommended example with all the best practices built-in.

Comment: `'blah' !~ /\d/ #=> true; 2blah' !~ /\d/ #=> false; 'blah2blah' !~ /\d/ #=> false`. Isn't that what's wanted?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Yikes, I was so caught up in looking at `/^^[0-9]+$/` that I didn’t read the question. Sorry.

Comment: I do that all the time, generally because I read a question the way I'd like it to be.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match?` like this:

```
'abcdef'.match?(/\d/)
 #=> false
```

Comment: Huh. I thought the trailing `?` was a typo at first, but it looks like that's new as of 2.4.0. Very nice.

Comment: @Glyoko They added that for those cases where you don't care about the match details, just that one occurred. Should be a lot faster in that case.

Comment: Having read Ryan's answer I realise I haven't actually answered the question asked. Nonetheless this shiny new method is still relevant here, so I will leave the answer up.

Comment: `+` is not needed here, is it?